# Adding libcurl to Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, curl, visual-studio-2012, libcurl

Okay, so im really fairly new at Visual C++ because I really dont want to stick with CodeBlocks because I have the feeling that Visual C++ is better for making Windows programs (Im use to the Visual Basic layout so Visual C++ helps)

Im trying to link libcurl into my project but really have no idea how to do it considering its  a new program.

I got to add the "include" folder to it by going selecting my project > Properties > Linker > General > "Additional Library Directories" > and adding the location of the "include" folder but thats pretty much it.

I need to add the rest but have no idea. Any help would work...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 is to point to directory that has the library, which you have already done.

Next step is to just add that library name here:

```
Project -> Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Dependencies
```

To see what flags are passed to the linker:

```
Project -> Properties -> Linker -> Command Line
```

To get detailed information on what the linker is doing:

```
Project -> Properties -> Linker -> General -> Show Progress -> Display all progress messages (/VERBOSE)
```

Hope this helps.